# UnboundLocalError in minimum path sum

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem in leetcode. I am new to leetcode. I am getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment.
What is exactly unboundlocalError mean?

```
class Solution:

    def minCostPath(self, arr):
        n = len(arr) # row 
        m = len(arr[0]) # colum
        dp = [[0 for i in range(n)] for j in range(m)]
        dp[0][0] = arr[0][0]
        for i in range(1, m):
            dp[i][0] = dp[i-1][0] + arr[i][0]
        for j in range(1, n):
            dp[0][j] = dp[0][j-1] + arr[0][j]
        for i in range(1, m):
            for j in range(1, n):
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i-1][j], dp[i][j-1], dp[i-1][j-1]) + arr[i][j]

        return dp[i][j]
```

Comment: Perhaps that should be `dp[m][n]`?  `i` or `j` may remain unset, if either `m` or `n` was 1, and therefore one of your `for` loops executed zero times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can also solve the problem (somewhat) without the extra space:

```
class Solution:
    def minPathSum(self, grid):
        row_length, col_length = len(grid), len(grid[0])
        for row in range(1, row_length):
            grid[row][0] += grid[row - 1][0]

        for col in range(1, col_length):
            grid[0][col] += grid[0][col - 1]

        for row in range(1, row_length):
            for col in range(1, col_length): 
                grid[row][col] += min(grid[row - 1][col], grid[row][col - 1])

        return grid[-1][-1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please explain why we are using ''if not grid: return''?

Answer (score 1):

This might happen for an array of length 1. Here's a much simpler version of your code that exhibits the same problem:

```
def func(length):
    for i in range(length):
        pass
    return i
```

Now consider:

```
In [4]: func(1)
Out[4]: 0

In [5]: func(0)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-ba0cd5a88f0a> in <module>
----> 1 func(0)

<ipython-input-3-d98b8e650438> in func(length)
      2     for i in range(length):
      3         pass
----> 4     return i
      5 

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed 'return dp[i][j]' to 'return dp[m-1][n-1]' and it got accepted.